# Google Play credit/debit card change

Tags: google-play-store

Is there a way to switch credit/debit card on Google Play?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried these [support instructions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/29072?hl=en)?

> **Update a Card**
>
> 1. Sign in to your account at https://wallet.google.com/manage.
> 2. Click **Payment methods** along the left side of the page.
> 3. Click **Edit** next to the card you would like to change. Once you've made the desired updates, click **Save**.
> 4. If you'd like to use this card as your default payment method, click **Set as default** next to the card.
> 5. Click **Save**.

Comment: It's April 2020, and it seems like Google has removed the ability to change the default payment method.  I don't see a Set as default.  Workaround is to delete all payment methods except the one I want it to use.